# How can i detect "going" to same route?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

I'm trying to hidde a view if the user try to go to the actual view again. Creating a toggle effect.
For example to show/hidde a modal box.

I tryied this code:

```
/* Root Instance */
const app = new Vue({
  router,
  watch: {
    '$route' (to, from) {
      if (to.path == from.path) {
        alert();
        router.go(-1);
      } else {
        alert(to.path + " != " + from.path);
      }
    }
  }
}).$mount("#app");
```

But since the hash is not changing at all, seems like vue router has nothing to route, for instance i'm unable to trigger the if block.

I could addEventListener to a elements to compare actual path against destination path and trigger the history.back() but seems like a bad solution. Also i'll still be unable to detect any other event capable of url redirection.

Do vue router provides a good solution?

Is there any available solution  to avoid handle manually all corner cases?

Answer (score -1):

Using watcher for $route would not work absolutely. You can use beforeRouteEnter method within the component or beforeRoute within directly the routes file. In your case, you would be able to store the count of attempts of a user to view a particular page. Based on that data, you can do whatever you want.

Comment: Navigation dosn't trigger at all when going to same route. Then beforeRouteEnter is not working. I just tryied it.